# Sending File to Apex class from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files

I need to send a file of max size 25 mb to my server side controller function from lightning component. I need to pass values to server, create record and then assign the file to it

I am using  of type file.

Not using fileupload component as it asks for the record id as I donot have it at he time of passing the record.

.

I went through below:
http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/
http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/09/25/file-upload-lightning-component/

any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You could use lightning:recordeditform or force:recorddata to create the record on the client side and access the Id to use with the lightning:fileUpload component. See the link below: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways I have used in the past (when lightning:fileUpload was not available) is to create a VF page specifically for file uploads, and then embed that VF page in a Lightning Component using iframe.

Your VF (say its named as MyFileUploadVF.page) would consist something as below:

```
<apex:inputFile id="componentId" value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>
```

And then in your Lightning Component, you can embed this using an iframe, something as below:

```
<iframe src="https://<instance-url>/apex/MyFileUploadVF"
                      width="298px" height="300px" frameBorder="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lightning:fileUpload` attaching the file to the User record, and then handle the event that returns you the `ContentDocumentId`. Once the target record is created, you can create a `ContentDocumentLink` from the new record to the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a workaround, while loading the page itself created a recordID in the background and  passed this id to lightning:fileupload , which enabled and I am able to attach the file.

If for some reason, user wants to drop the idea of creating the record and he clicks on cancel button, I delete the record if he/she was creating a record and not updating it.